# Why are there holidays marking VE/VJ/Armistice Day in different cultures, while many other wars aren't commemorated at their conclusion?

Tags: war, american-civil-war, american-revolution, ceremony

I have tried to research why there seems to be commemorations and/or holidays marking the end of the World War in countries around the world, but seemingly in the United states we do not mark the end of wars as a common practice.

Some prime examples are both the Civil War and Revolutionary War both had both notable endings at Appotomax Court House and Yorktown/Treaty of Paris respectively.  I understand some wars are hard to mark an end, yet we usually find the signing of an agreement to be celebratory conclusion of hostilities.  Some wars are considered to be events where official recognition is hard to do, such as the Vietnam War.

It seems more common that commemoration of individual major events get more national attention, especially in the US, such as the 4th of July, which commemorates our declaration of war.

I understand there could be some opinion/subjectiveness here, but I was trying to understand how cultures commemorate these wars in historical.

Comment: @SteveBird Thank you, I should've been more judicious about the word "we".  Depending where you're from there are holidays for these, Veteran's day used to be Armistice Day.  But I do believe you're right, that other than RI in the US there is no other celebration of VJ day, and VE day is not celebrated within the US.  However, internationally there are countries that celebrate both.  I should update/change my question.

Comment: @SteveBird I tried to clarify my question more.  I hope I've now made it more understandable about my confusion.  I also wanted to remove "celebrate" because, in retrospect, I don't think that was the right choice of words.

Comment: In the UK, Remembrance Sunday started after WWI as Armistice Day, 11 November. With respect, it may be difficult for Americans to understand the sheer shock of WW1, the scale of the slaughter,  the horrors of trench war, and the first "total war". I know USA came into it, but late and, apart from service personnel, was never in such close proximity to the fighting. For the UK, it was a culture shock par excellence.

Comment: Technically, the American Civil War ended after Appotomax.  Johnson surrendered to Sherman after Lincoln's assassination, and there were various other surrenders.  It sort of petered out, which is why Memorial Day is not associated with the end of the war in particular.

Comment: The UK had a public holiday for the 75th anniversary of VE Day in 2020 (though commemorations were limited because of lockdown), but the date isn't commemorated annually.

Comment: It's common to celebrate the last major war, e.g. in the UK, [Trafalgar Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trafalgar_Day) reportedly declined in importance after World War One. This question still seems a bit too vague. Which cultures? What kind of celebrations (are you only interested in public holidays)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to depend on the degree of trauma a war caused, and the time since its conclusion. Some examples:

For the UK, WWI was extremely traumatic, because of the vast number of casualties, and the way they *kept on happening* without the Army seeming able to change that. Commemoration at the end of the war seemed natural and became a tradition. The tradition absorbed commemoration of WWII, and all the wars since, none of which have been on a similar scale. The tradition has evolved, in that most events are now held on the Sunday closest to 11th November, although some people hold a two-minute silence on the 11th anyway. The effects of WWI are still visible in my family: my maternal grandmother was one of four sisters, all born between 1895 and 1902, only two of whom ever married because of the shortage of men.

France holds national holidays for both Armistice Day and VE Day; both wars were very traumatic. The shortage of men after WWI was worse in France than in the UK.

Russia commemorates [Victory Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victory_Day_(9_May)) on 9th May with a public holiday. WWII was immensely traumatic for the USSR, and commemoration became a part of the Soviet position that they had defeated Nazi Germany themselves.  There is some truth in that, given how much of the German Army they defeated.

There are no international rules about the way wars are commemorated. Each country makes its own decisions.

Comment: Thanks.  I appreciate this response.  I'm glad to know it's at least inconsistent across the board.